# Name a New Data Frame From An Extracted Column Name In A Old Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, r-colnames

My original data frame has 311 columns and ~6,000 rows with the first column being the transaction date and columns 2:311 are the number of daily transactions. I am trying to extract specific column names to subsequently create new data frames based on a subset of the data.

I use the code below to specify which column in the dataframe:

```
Product <- colnames(Volumes[2])[1] #choosing product
```

This returns the following: `DSL_BC_03AG`

Once I have the result, I want it to be the name of a completely new [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe). I have tried it multiple ways, all have failed. One approach I have tried is listed below:

```
colnames(Volumes[2])[1] <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 2))
```

I receive the following error:

> Warning message: In colnames(Volumes[2])[1] <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,
>   ncol = 2,  :   number of items to replace is not a multiple of
>   replacement length

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `assign(colnames(Volumes[2])[1],  as.data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)))`

Comment: Allen, this worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.